# How to display the background picture on full size in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Like the following displayed, every background picture in the lwc tile component is not fully displayed, the CSS style is as this:

```
.tile {
    width: 60%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 2px !important;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  }
```

[image: the tiles]

[image: the full picture]

The actual picture of the 'All in Family':
↑

How to fix this problem?}

Comment: There's more than just one thing wrong with your CSS: the text isn't supposed to be overlapping either (I presume you're doing the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lwc_specialist); you'll need to follow the directions.

Comment: HI, @sfdcfox ,    thanks for your reply. 
I copied the css style exactly as the same with the trailhead. (Yes, this is the lwc superbadge project).
But nothing changed. The background pictures are still displayed half even smaller.

Comment: I instead used  <image> tag to complete it , it seems  look like all right.
But the way lwc superbadge in the trailhead instructed resulted in half shown, unless how hard I tried.